# sort checkboxes in html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I Am sorting check boxes with this code

```
function sortGiveNamesFilter() {
    $('#subfilterNamesContainer label').sort(function(a, b) {
        var $a = $(a).find(':checkbox'),
            $b = $(b).find(':checkbox');

        if ($a.hasClass('default') && !$b.hasClass('default'))
            return -1;
        else if (!$a.hasClass('default') && $b.hasClass('default'))
            return 1;

        if ($a.is(':checked') && !$b.is(':checked'))
            return -1;
        else if (!$a.is(':checked') && $b.is(':checked'))
            return 1;

        if ($a.val() < $b.val())
            return -1;
        else if ($a.val() > $b.val())
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }).appendTo('#subfilterNamesContainer');

    $('#subfilterNamesContainer .default:last, #subfilterNamesContainer :checked:last').closest('label').after('<hr />');
}
```

as we can see in img 1 it giving me propar result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VS29.jpg)

but when it comes to 2 digit numeric valus its not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJyb3.jpg)
where i am doing worng?

Comment: Well they are NOT numeric values for a start

Comment: ok sorry then whats solution

Comment: Also neither of those results look sorted correctly

Comment: What has PHP got to do with this

Comment: It would also probably help our understanding if you showed the HTML that this code is processing

Comment: Please show a proper [mre] of your issue when asking questions like this, and not just a snippet that lacks context.

Comment: hey guy, should you not have sorted the parentElement instead of the label in it? you're using this $('#subfilterNamesContainer label'); you'd select all elements having those checkboxes.